# How to get Section Option value in real time

Tags: php, html, real-time

Forgive me if this is a repeated question but I am having trouble finding the correct wording for my issue.  I have a client that wants me to redo their log page.  They want a drop-down box with a list of all the unique cities in their database.  I have this part done.  The next part is when the user clicks on one of the options, all the logs for that city display.  My issue is I cannot figure out how to get the value of select box.  I know I can do it with a form submit, but I want to be able to click the box and show it in real time.  Here is the code for the drop-down if needed:

Drop-down code:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT location FROM tbl_overnight");

if (!mysql_num_rows($select)) {
    echo "<option value='none'>No Locations...</option>";
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['location']."'>".$row['location']."</option>";
    }
};

?>
```

The code for the logs so far is similar to the code above except for the display.  I read somewhere that I may have to use AJAX so I can get the real-time value then convert it to a php variable but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

If there is another post that is similar to this that I did not see then please link it in a comment below and I will look at it and remove this posting.

Comment: You have two options (a) fetch all the logs initially and show/hide onChange (of dropdown), or (b) fetch no logs initially, but fetch them via AJAX onChange.  Either way, you will want to consider something like jQuery to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking about doing the first one.  I would just use the onChange event then?

Comment: Use the jQuery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

Comment: You will need ajax because if you fetch all logs once and displaying them later won't be a real-time work. This action will show old logs even if they are updated after you visit a page. Take a look here to get data by using jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ Also don't use old mysql_* functions, use PDO. Take a look here and read the red box to learn why you should not use mysql_* functions : http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: post some html showing your selects, ajax can be implemented with very little code on either end

Comment: I may not be able to try out the solutions for a few days as my client has other more important  issues.  Thank you all for the help and I will mark the answer when I have time to sit and go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in php you could use ajax and the onChange event in javascipt to do this
this tutorial may will help you to do what you want

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try later tonight.